Building custom Cross-validation in Pycaret()
I have been working on a slightly different cross-validation for a specific dataset I want to integrate with PyCaret. However, once it runs there is no output from compare_models(). I believe it is an issue with the CV initialization. Here is the code:
class LeaveOneGroupOut_Custom(BaseCrossValidator):
  def __init__(self, group_columns=['A, 'B'], random_state=None):
        self.group_columns = group_columns
        self.groups = pd.concat([dataset[i] for i in group_columns]).unique()

  def get_n_splits(self, X=None, y=None):
      if self.groups is None:
          raise ValueError("The 'groups' parameter should not be None.")
      return len(np.unique(self.groups))

  def split(self, X, y):
      unique_groups = list(set(self.groups))
      group_columns=['A', 'B']

      for group in unique_groups:
        train_indices = X[(X[group_columns[0]] != group) & (X[group_columns[1]] != group)].index.values
        test_indices = X[(X[group_columns[0]] == group) | (X[group_columns[1]] == group)].index.values
        
        yield train_indices, test_indices

custom_split = LeaveOneGroupOut_Custom()
custom_split.get_n_splits(X = df) # it returns the correct number of splits; and correct splits checked manually

s = setup(df, target='target', session_id=123, fold_strategy=custom_split)
best = compare_models()
print(best) # [ ]

I found very little documentation on how to create a bespoke CV iterator and cannot figure out what I'm missing here.
Thanks for the help!
I tried running the compare_models() Pycaret AutoML function with my custom cross-validation generator but no output was shown. It was observed that it would initialise the CV but then skip to other ML models.
